# how to inject a file into http request

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-testing

i have a test case:

```
$response = $this->postJson('api/unit/'.$unit->id.'/import',['file' =>Storage::get('file/file.xlsx')]);
    $response->assertJsonFragment(['a'=>'b']);
```

my controller:

```
public function import(Request $request, Unit $unit)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'file|required_without:rows',
        'rows' => 'array|required_without:file',
        'dry_run' => 'boolean',
    ]);
    if ($request->has('rows')) {
        //
    } else {
        $results = $request->file('file');
    }

    return "ok";
}
```

but i think my test case is wrong,because when i dd($reuqest->file('file')) in my controller, it return null.
So, how can i request file into my controller.
please help

Comment: Have you serialized the file?

Comment: what is serialized the file, and how to do this?! @DimitriMostrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UploadFile like this:

```
$fileName= 'file.png';
$filePath=sys_get_temp_dir().'/'.$fileName;
$mimeTypeFile=mime_content_type($filePath);
$file=new UploadedFile($filePath, $fileName, $mimeTypeFile, filesize('$filePath'), null, true)
$response = $this->postJson('api/unit/'.$unit->id.'/import',['file' =>$file]);
$response->assertJsonFragment(['a'=>'b']);
```

with null is The error constant of the upload, true is test mode
more detail for Symfony UploadedFile, read [this](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-file-uploads.

Try something like this. Import  **use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;**

```
UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.xlsx', $size);
Storage::disk('file')->assertExists('file.xlsx');
```

Comment: i want to use my file