# how to upload file with json post request in laravel unit test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-testing, phpunit

i want create a test case for test upload file.
it must use my file to test. because i want test upload file excel and import data from this file,after that, check this data from database.
i tried:

```
$response = $this->postJson('api/unit/'.$unit->id.'/import',['file' =>Storage::get('file/file.xlsx')]);
$response->assertJsonFragment(['a'=>'b']);
```

but it is not working, beacuse when i check $request->all() in my controller, it return null.
Please help!

Comment: may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408134/how-to-test-file-upload-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: i want use real file, but not fake file@JigneshJoisar

Comment: yes see the first answer @the manh Nguyen

Comment: Can you explain the input parameters?

Comment: this question like [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775833/10606096) could be help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148681/10319107) answer